# django rest framework filter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm working with API made from Django rest framework,
I am trying to make a filter to a JSON 
This is my  `serializers.py` file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Establecimiento,Categoria,Ciudad,Zona
import django_filters

class EstablecimientoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Establecimiento
        depth = 1

        fields =  ('nombre',
                   'ciudad',
                   'categoria',
                   'direccion',
                   'telefono',
                   'precioMinimo',
                   'precioMaximo',)
```

and this my `views.py` file

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import EstablecimientoSerializer, CategoriaSerializer
from models import *
from rest_framework import filters
from rest_framework import generics

class EstablecimientoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Establecimiento.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EstablecimientoSerializer
    filter_fields = ('categoria',)
```

Then in  the `EstablecimientoViewSet` class, I put a `filter_fields = ('categoria',)`
to filter the  url's API  with the category field

If I add the filter to the query parameters, the result set does not change, it shows all data unfiltered.

```
...establecimiento?establecimiento=bar
```

How can I make this filter  about this model?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to define filter backend and all related fields you're planning to filter on:

```
class EstablecimientoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('categoria', 'categoria__titulo',)
```

example:

```
URL?categoria__titulo=Categoria 1
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I am using Django 1.7. Are you sure Filter fields and backends work with ModelViewset too? This works perfectly with APIListview from generics.

Comment: in my case with DJango 1.7 i am getting a `Meta.fields contains a field that isn't defined on this FilterSet` also using modelviewsets

Comment: @psychok7, you have to add a comma to the end of the tuple filter_fields. Doing that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 7):

it's also possible to supply your own **Filter** class, which may give you more options and flexibility

```
import sys, django_filters, json, io

class TaskFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    tag  = django_filters.CharFilter(name='tags__name', lookup_type='iexact')
    university = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='poster__university', lookup_type='exact')

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = {
            'poster': ['exact'],
            'tasker': ['exact'],
            'status': ['exact'],
            'created': ['lt', 'gt']
        }
```

In this example I got filters

1. poster = 1
2. tasker = 115
3. status = O
4. created__lt=2015-09-22
   17:39:01.184681 (so I can filter datetime by values LESS THEN)
5. created__gt=2015-09-22 17:39:01.184681 (or GREATER THAN provided
   value)

Also I can hide foreign fields with custom filter fields, in this case it's **tag** & **university**. Plus I can provide comparison operator (**lookup_type**)

Sample request:

```
GET /api/v1/tasks/?offset=0&status=O&limit=100&university=1&ordering=-created&created__lt=2015-09-22 17:39:01.184681&tag=sport HTTP/1.1
Host: domain.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: token 61cbd3c7c2656d4e24edb31f5923a86910c67b7c
User-Timezone: US/Pacific
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, it works when I put the comma at the end of my filter_fields.

eg.

```
filter_fields = ('distribuidor',)
```

Comment: Looks like they're already doing that. Not sure your solution adds anything.

Comment: This worked for me. I had a tuple with only 1 item. Didn't realize I was missing a comma on my tuple.