# Django Rest Framework : Filtering against Table Field value

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm improving my Django Web App with `Django Rest API` part and I have a question according to `filtering` against table field value.

I have my **serializer class** like this :

```
class IndividuResearchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    class Meta :
        model = Individu
        fields = [
            'id',
            'NumeroIdentification',
            'Nom',
            'Prenom',
            'VilleNaissance',
        ]
```

My **views.py** file with this class :

```
class IndividuResearchAPIView(ListAPIView) :
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
    serializer_class = IndividuResearchSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Individu.objects.all()
        NIU = self.request.query_params.get('NumeroIdentification')
        queryset = queryset.filter(NumeroIdentification=NIU)

        return queryset
```

And my **pythonic file** which let to simulate connexion from another software based to `API Rest` :

```
import requests

mytoken = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IkFkbWluIiwiZXhwIjoxNTE5NzMxOTAxLCJlbWFpbCI6InZhbGVudGluQGRhdGFzeXN0ZW1zLmZyIiwib3JpZ19pYXQiOjE1MTk3MjgzMDF9.493NzJ4OUEzTKu5bZsZ9UafMwQZHz9pESMsYgfd0RLc"
url = 'http://localhost:8000/Api/Identification/search/'


NIU = "I-19312-00001-305563-2"

response = requests.get(url, NIU = NIU, headers={'Authorization': 'JWT {}'.format(mytoken)})

print(response.text)
```

I would like to enter a `NIU value` into my request in order to filter my table and return the object according to this `NIU`.

For example, in my database I have this object :

[image]

I would like to return this object thanks to my API but I don't know if my function `get_queryset` is well-writen and How I can write my API request.

Into my **urls.py** file, I have :

```
url(r'^search/$', IndividuResearchAPIView.as_view() , name="Research"),
```

So I am not making a filtering by URL.

I read these posts in order to get more element :

[Django REST framework - filtering against query param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182725/django-rest-framework-filtering-against-query-param)

[django rest framework filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374253/django-rest-framework-filter)

and obviously DRF doc : http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-current-user

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you need to use this url to filter: `http://localhost:8000/Api/Identification/search/?NumeroIdentification=NUA_value`. With requests library try to pass it with params argument: `response = requests.get(url, params={'NumeroIdentification': NIU}, headers={'Authorization': 'JWT {}'.format(mytoken)})`

Comment: Yes exactly what I expected ! Please can you share your message as an answer in order to validate it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this url to filter: `http://localhost:8000/Api/Identification/search/?NumeroIdentification=NUA_value`. With requests library try to pass it with params argument: `response = requests.get(url, params={'NumeroIdentification': NIU}, headers={'Authorization': 'JWT {}'.format(mytoken)})`.